# Push data from external API on AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-kinesis

I am new to AWS ecosystem. I'm building a (near) real-time system, where data comes from external API. The API is updated every 10 seconds, so I would like to consume and populate my Kinesis pipeline as soon as new data appears.
However, I'm not sure which tool use for that. I did a small research and, I think, I have two options:

- AWS lambda which is triggered every 10 seconds and puts data on Kinesis
- AWS StepFunction

What is the standard approach for a given use case?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Step functions is created by Lambda functions. That is, each step in a workflow is actually a Lambda function. You can think of a workflow created by AWS Step Functions as a chain of Lambda functions.

If you are not familiar with how to create a workflow see this AWS tutorial:

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)

(you can create a Lambda function in any supported programming language. This one happens to use Java).

Now, to answer your question, using a workflow to populate a Kinesis data stream is possible. You can build a Lambda function that gathers data (using logic in your Lambda function), and then invoke the **putRecord** operation of Kinesis to populate the data stream. You can create a scheduled event that fires off every x min based on a CRON expression.

If you do use a CRON expression, you can use the AWS Step Functions API to fire off the workflow. That is, create another Lambda function that is scheduled to fire say every 10 mins. Then in this Lambda funciton, use the Step Functions API to invoke the workflow. Now the workflow can populate the Kinesis data stream with data.